# How to mirror video on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video

In my app I need to get mirrored and rotated copies of video files on iPhone.
What the best and fastest way to do this?

Comment: I've never worked with video. So I havn't tried anything. Just searched in web to find some examples, but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAReplicatorLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) on for size.

> The CAReplicatorLayer class creates a specified number of copies of
>   its sublayers (the source layer), each copy potentially having
>   geometric, temporal and color transformations applied to it.